# Yahoo / Gtalk link in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I have a website developed in Joomla. I want to add my gtalk id on image of gtalk. That is if any user clicks on image of gtalk than he/she should be able to add my id to their gtalk account. Same way for Yahoo.

I have tried to do it in module with code

```
<a mce_href="http://mce_host/gtalk:call?jid=abc@gmail.com" href="gtalk:call?jid=abc@gmail.com">
```

but joomla removes my code `mce_href="http://mce_host/gtalk:call?jid=abc@gmail.com"`

Comment: Are you putting the code in a custom html module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code will get stripped out on save if you have an editor enabled. Disable the editor from the config by setting to none and then Joomla will not strip out your code.